# iOS Push Notifications: App as Provider?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I understand the basic concept of having a provider talk to Apple's Push Notification Server which then pushes the notification to the phone. Usually, the provider is an app server running on some machine somewhere completely separate from the app.

However, we don't currently have a separate server, and don't yet need one as everything is currently handled in-app. **So, is there any way we can use the app itself as the provider to send a notification to Apple's server and thus to another phone?**

Basic concept: we have a game and when a user completes 70% of the level, we'd like to notify his competitors that he's close to finishing the game (or that he has finished at 100%).

If it's possible, are there any security concerns with this approach?

*P.S. The app already knows who the competitors are because it displays them in a UITableView.*

Comment: I think you should try using PushApps, it's a platform for sending Push Notifications that manages the Server Side that communicates with apple for you. It also has a "notification by event" option, so you can send a notification "directly" from the app. http://www.pushapps.mobi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it's possible. If you include the push certificate with your app, and you have a way to send the device token of each device to all other devices that may need to push to that device, you can push a notification directly from one device to another.

However, in practice, that would require opening and closing many connections to the APNS servers frequently (you'll need a connection for each device, and every time a device loses network connection - which may happen often - you'll have to re-open that connection), which will probably cause Apple to block your app from connecting to their APNS server (since they would interpret it a DDoS attack).

Therefore you should use a server.

Comment: Thanks Eran for the clarification! We'll look at using an existing service like Amazon SNS as our server platform so we don't have to host anything ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors to this question: we wound up ditching [Amazon SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) since we spent nearly 8 hours and couldn't get it working the way we wanted. Instead, we setup [Parse Push](https://parse.com/products/push) in rough 15 minutes with exactly what we wanted to do, so I would definitely recommend giving it a look.